# Roomshare - avoiding the worst choice

Tags: probability, randomness

I'm moving in a new shared house with two other people. There are three bedrooms in the house and we will draw numbers from a hat for the rooms.

All agree that room one is better than room two and room two is better than room three.

I would be happy with either room one or room two.

Would I be better off to draw from the hat first, draw second or draw third, a once-off decision that is made up-front?

Is there a more general strategy for when to draw a room from the hat, given $n$ rooms, with room $i$ better than room $j$, for $1 \le i < j \le n$, with any of the first $k$ rooms being acceptable?

Comment: It may be better to not draw from a hat, but rather agree on a difference in price to make it fair. http://www.spliddit.org/apps/rent gives you envy-free and efficient solutions to this problem.

Comment: The question becomes a lot more interesting if you put a goat behind one of the 3 doors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there's no decision-making involved, but everyone is simply assigned the room they pick out of the hat (which we assume is uniformly random), then the order doesn't matter. By symmetry, you have a 2/3 chance of ending up with a room you like no matter what. You can double-check this by enumerating the possible orders that the rooms are drawn from the hat:

```
1 2 3
1 3 2
2 1 3
2 3 1
3 1 2
3 2 1
```

Each room appears in each position exactly twice, so the probability that room $i$ is picked by the person in position $j$ is always $\tfrac13$.